# How do I write a log likelihood function when I have 2 mean values for my pdf?

Tags: statistics

I have been given the following pdf :

fT (t; B, C) = ( exp(-t/C) - exp(-t/B) ) / ( C - B )  ,  (t>0)
where the overall mean is B+C.

I am unsure as to how to write the log likelihood function of B and C.

The next part of the Q asks me to derive the equations that would have to be solved in order to find the max likelihood estimators of B and C.

I would be grateful for any help =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, the log-likelihood is given by
$$
\ln \mathcal{L}(B,C|x_1 , \ldots ,x_n ) = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {\ln f(x_i|B,C)}.
$$
Thus, in our example, 
$$
\ln \mathcal{L}(B,C|x_1 , \ldots ,x_n ) = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {\ln \bigg[\frac{{e^{ - x_i /C}  - e^{ - x_i /B} }}{{C - B}}\bigg]} .
$$

EDIT: In view of the next part of the question, it may be useful to write
$$
\ln \mathcal{L}(B,C|x_1 , \ldots ,x_n ) = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {\ln [e^{ - x_i /C}  - e^{ - x_i /B} ]}  - n\ln (C - B).
$$

Comment: I have just realised for my Q I first need to write down the likelihood function. How would I do this?

Comment: The likelihood function is given by $\mathcal{L}(B,C|x_1 , \ldots ,x_n ) = \prod\nolimits_{i = 1}^n {f(x_i |B,C)} $.

Comment: Evaluate the log-likelihood and derive the equations that would have to be solved in order to find the Maximum Likelihood Estimators for B and C. This is the Q i was given, for the second part where it says to solve the estimators for B and C, would you take that as having to solve B and C seperately, or as a whole? Thanks =)

Comment: Wouldn't it be enough to write the equations corresponding to $\frac{\partial }{{\partial C}}\ln \mathcal{L}(B,C|x_1 , \ldots ,x_n ) = 0$ and $\frac{\partial }{{\partial B}}\ln \mathcal{L}(B,C|x_1 , \ldots ,x_n ) = 0$?